# How do nested functions get compiled?

Tags: memory, compiler-construction, nested-function

When I have 2 functions in D like this:

```
void func() {
    void innerFunc() {
        import std.stdio;
        writeln(x);
    }

    int x = 5;
    innerFunc();
}
```

When I call `func` this will print 5. How does it work? Where in memory does the 5 get stored? How does innerFunc know it has to print 5?

Comment: This is very broad... Basically, your compiler reads the source code, interprets it according to the syntactic and semantic rules of the language, and generates machine code to accomplish the task it has been given. Depending on the sophistication of the compiler, it may completely rearrange your code, as long as the result is the same, so your example could conceivably generate the exact same code as `void func() { writeln(5); }`. It may even completely leave out the function and just insert `writeln(5)` at every place where `func()` is called...

Comment: @twalberg I know it can optimize this out, but what if no optimization is done?

Comment: Does your compiler have the option to emit assembler code instead of object code? If so, you can investigate how it does that yourself. I'm not entirely sure what you are unclear on, but as a guess, the nested function is just a semantic construct that implies certain scoping rules in the source code - if it is not optimized away, it is probably emitted as a regular non-nested function that only gets called from one place, possibly with a differently-mangled name, and  maybe a different function prologue/postlogue. I'm not overly familiar with D and the available compilers for it...

Comment: @twalberg It's not necessarily D specific though, there are plenty of languages with this behaviour. In fact I was surprised standard C/++ doesn't have this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I attempt to answer this in broad terms. This type of issue arises in a number of languages that permit nested function definitions (including Ada and Pascal).

Normally, a variable like "x" is allocated on the processor stack. That's the normal process in any language that permits recursion.

When a nested function is called, a descriptor for the enclosing function's stack frame gets passed as hidden argument.

funct() then knows that x is located at some offset specified by the base pointer register.

innerFunct () knows the offset of x but has to derive the base from the hidden argument. It can't use its own base pointer value because it will be different from funct(). And, if innerFunct () called itself, the base pointer value would be different in each invocation.

Comment: So nesting functions is actually less performing than putting everything global because it has to pass pointers?

Comment: Passing an additional pointer is one more push instruction. If you were writing code to manage context switches in an operating system, it might make a difference. For most real world applications, this level of optimization is not noticable.